# How do I have 3 images on one line and 2 on another?

Tags: html

I'm editing the following code from a template. I would like to fix 3 images centred on the top line and 2 centred on the line below. Currently, this code is showing 4 images on the top line and just the one below.

I also don't want to break the responsive for mobile devices if this is possible.

Thank you in advance!

```
<section class="feature-area pt-120" id="feature">    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center home-area-title">
                <div class="col-lg-8">                  
                    <h1 class="text-white text-center">Most Powerful Features</h1>
                    <p class="subs text-center mt-10 mx-auto">
                        There are advances being made in science and technology everyday, and a good example of this is the LCD monitor. LCD monitors have several benefits over the old chunky.
                    </p>                            
                </div>
            </div>              
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/card1.png" alt="">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/card2.png" alt="">
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/card3.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/card5.png" alt="">
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="img/card5.png" alt="">
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>                                                      
            </div>
        </div>    
    </section>
```

Comment: Please include enough code (html, css, etc) for us to be able to duplicate the problem. My first guess is that your issue is in your CSS code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see you are using a bootstrap enabled template. I will recommend you go through bootstrap documentation to have a better understanding but this is what you need to do:

The three images you want on the first line should be inside a class row not multiple rows. For example I want to have 3 divs on a line.

It should be 
Every other elements you want in that line will be inside this div

```
              </div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Do you know how I would centre these images now?

Comment: Include .mx-auto class to your row div.  Read more about horizontal centering in bootstrap here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/